# Split big insert query in batches using php pdo with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the following function to insert multiple records into the database. This function adds records into the mysql db using a single query.

```
function addHostBulk($value, $label, $group, $type, $user)
{
    $res = array("type" => intval($type), "value" => $value, "label" => $label, "group_id" => $group, "owner" => intval($user['id']));

        $hosts = $common->cidrToRange($res['value'], $user); //Returns array with all hosts from this CIDR range /array('hosts' => array('1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.5.', ...)/
        $final_count = count($hosts['hosts']);

        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        $query = ("INSERT INTO hosts (`id`, `type`, `value`, `label`, `group_id`, `owner`) VALUES ");
        $qPart = array_fill(0, count($hosts['hosts']), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query .=  implode(",",$qPart);

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

        $i = 1;
        foreach($hosts['hosts'] as $host){
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $common->uuid(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $host, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['label'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['group_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['owner'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                unset($host);
        }

        $statement->execute();
        $this->db->commit();

    return true;
}
```

Code is working fine, however if I try to insert about 30000 records at once I'm hitting the mysql limit and exception is raised: **"General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders"**.

As far as I know, I can fix this by splitting the query into small batches. Splitting it by 1000 batches will be fine (one query has 6 placeholders x 1000 records = 6k placeholders. Mysql limit is ~ 65k placeholders).

Can anyone help me with splitting it?

Comment: why would you even consider inserting so many duplicates ? I've seen de-normalization, but this is ridiculous.  You don't need to 'split' the query, you need a database redesign. read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization for start

Comment: @Sorin.. what do you mean by duplicates? I'm just inserting many rows per single query. They are NOT duplicates. They have the same fields but not the same values!

Comment: I've pointed you to a link, you should read that before responding. You are inserting duplicates, all your rows have the same values except two (actually one, UUID in this case is probably useless) which is contrary to the second normal form. I doubt there is any real reason to do what you are doing, and I'm willing to bet that your "design" is wrong.

Comment: @Sorin, please check code carefully. I'm inserting different hosts (ip addresses) calculated from cidrToRange function.

Comment: Yea, that's the one different field ... the rest are DUPLICATES - read the link, for god sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addHostBulk($value, $label, $group, $type, $user)
{
    $res = array("type" => intval($type), "value" => $value, "label" => $label, "group_id" => $group, "owner" => intval($user['id']));

    $hosts = $common->cidrToRange($res['value'], $user); //Returns array with all hosts from this CIDR range /array('hosts' => array('1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.5.', ...)/
    $totalHosts = count($hosts['hosts']);
    $batchSize = 1000;

    for ($idx=0; $idx*$batchSize < $totalHosts; $idx++) { 
        $hostsPartial = array_slice($hosts['hosts'], $idx*$batchSize, $batchSize);

        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        $query = ("INSERT INTO hosts (`id`, `type`, `value`, `label`, `group_id`, `owner`) VALUES ");
        $qPart = array_fill(0, count($hostsPartial), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query .=  implode(",",$qPart);

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

        $i = 1;
        foreach($hostsPartial as $host){
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $common->uuid(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $host, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['label'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['group_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['owner'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                unset($host);
        }

        $statement->execute();
        $this->db->commit();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT try to create one gigantic SQL statement and bind thousands of variables!
This is wrong on many points: number of bound variables is limited, SQL statement size is also limited to something like 1MB, etc...

Instead, change your code to use single static INSERT statement like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO hosts (`id`, `type`, `value`, `label`, `group_id`, `owner`)"
       . "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Then do something like this:

```
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  # important!
$this->db->beginTransaction();
$statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
foreach($hosts['hosts'] as $host) {
     # bind 6 variables...
     $statement->execute();
}
$this->db->commit();
```

This code will work for millions of rows in one transaction, and should work very fast.

Comment: @downvoter: it would be nice to explain what's wrong with this answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, put condition in foreach to check if there are more than 1000 records then insert 1st 1000 and loop for other like this

```
    $i = 1;
    $totalCount = 0;
    foreach($hosts['hosts'] as $host){

            $statement->bindParam($i++, $common->uuid(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam($i++, $host, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['label'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['group_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam($i++, $res['owner'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            unset($host);

            if($i==1000)
            {
               $statement->execute();
               $this->db->commit();
               $i=0;
            }

    }

    //check for last time if any records left then you have to insert those records also

    if($i<1000)
    {
         $statement->execute();
         $this->db->commit();

    }
```